# Elastic Search using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How to sort data using multiple filters in elastic search using NEST queries.

1. I need to apply two fields lets say **price** and **kilometer** for cars in results set. I want the results sorted based on these fields by **ASC** or **DESC**.
2. How to get top five results based on conditions or some filters.

Please provide some links if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should answer your questions:

```cs
 IEnumerable<string> searchableFields = new List<string>() { "price", "kilometer" };

 SearchDescriptor<T> descriptor = new SearchDescriptor<T>();
 descriptor = descriptor.Size(5).OnFields(searchableFields)
                .Sort(s => s.OnField("price").Descending().OnField("kilometer").Ascending());

 var result = client.Search<T>(body => descriptor);
```

Comment: Thats good. but Lets say i have a document set of 100 results. I want top five to be sorted using price and KM AND remaining 95 i want to apply other sort(other filter) but all 100 results should be in one object.

Comment: .OnFields() is not allowed with SearchDescriptor type object.